# Compression level, Obfuscation and password in c# DotNetZip library

Tags: c#, compression, dotnetzip

Here i am using this code to set **maximum compression level**, **Obfuscate files contents** (at least for .txt files) inside the output zip and to set password for the **output zip file name** prevent user from seeing files inside the zip:

```
zip.Password = "123456789";
zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;
zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
zip.AddDirectory(@"d:\testfolder");
zip.Save(@"d:\savehere");
```

but this is what will happen:

The password will be on each files inside the zip instead of the output zip itself.

> *1)*  How can i set a password for the main output zip not each file ?

Files content can be read by user after entering password. and it seems the encryption wont work.

> *2)*  How can i encrypt files content while they are in the zip ?

The compression level is set to Best(maximum) but the compressed file size is barely reduced (for 600mb of diffrent type of files is 5mb)

> *3)*  Is there a way to make the final file more compact using the library ?

Im using **Ionic.zip.dll** not the **reduced** dll

also tried to move `AddDirectory` over `CompressionLevel` and `Encryption` to see if its a typing mistake:

```
zip.Password = "123456789";
zip.AddDirectory(@"d:\testfolder");
zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;
zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
zip.Save(@"d:\savehere");
```

Comment: `and it seems the encryption wont work` What makes you say that? `The compression level is set to Best(maximum) but the compressed file size is barely reduced (for 600mb of diffrent type of files is 5mb)` What kind of files are you compressing?

Comment: Because the txt files content have not changed while its in the zip and user can see whats in it. tried for combination of exe,dll,dat,ini,jpg,txt,ico,rar,...

Comment: `Because the txt files content have not changed while its in the zip and user can see whats in it.` How did you examine the contents of the zip (what tool did you use)? Did you have to specify the password to see the contents of the zip?

Comment: yes, user first enter the pass then see the content

Comment: actually want to prevent antiviruses from seeing .txt and other files content

Comment: As this is accpeted i think i got all my answers. Thank you so much.